# MAAS server can't find juju server

Tags: networking, server, juju, maas

I installed MAAS(Computer 1) and Juju(Computer 2) with router. 
I checked that both of installation is complete.
But, It didn't work any juju operation(status, deploy, etc..). 
Maybe, MAAS server can't find juju node.

In router, It attached MAAS server and Juju node. However, juju node's name isn't shown in router's internal network status page.
For example,

192.168.x.x(maas)    <---MAAS node

192.168.x.x          <---juju node

I guess this problem. Can you help this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The MAAS server shouldn't need to see the machine where juju is installed; instead, the machine running juju needs to be [configured](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-maas.html) to use the MAAS server.

Please note that there's an [error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1256055) on that page: you almost certainly want to omit the `admin-secret` and `default-series` settings in the `environments.yaml` file.